# ovrreride anchor style in .ui-state-hover a from jqueryui css

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI css for my tables, applying styles using a Jquery function. For  each row on mouse over  all td tags gets a css class **ui-state-hover** and this class  defines color for anchor

```
.ui-state-hover a,
.ui-state-hover a:hover,
.ui-state-hover a:link,
.ui-state-hover a:visited {
    color: #212121;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I don't  want color  **#212121**  for my anchor in table and leave it default blue which comes from my css

```
a,
    a:link,
    a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: blue ;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    a:visited {
        color: purple ;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

I don't want to add **!important** to anchor color style in my css  as it does it globally.
Advice me how to override  **.ui-state-hover a color**.
 [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wY2Whcct1kSUNzWh1Juz?p=preview)

my hmtl code

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--<script  type="text/javascript"  src="../jquery-ui-1.11.1/external/jquery/jquery.js"/>
    <link type="text/css"  src="../jquery-ui-1.11.1/jqueryui.css">
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="../jquery-ui-1.11.1/jqueryui.js"/>
        -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <style>
    body {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 12px;
}
a,
    a:link,
    a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: blue ;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    a:visited {
        color: purple ;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a.ui-state-hover{
        color: blue !important;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        tblCss();
    });
    var tblCss =function(){
        $("table").each(function(){
            jqueryUITbl(this);
        });
    }

    var jqueryUITbl  =function(tbl){
         $this = $(tbl);
         $this.on('mouseover mouseout', 'tbody tr', function (event) {
              console.log('  mouseover')
             $(this).children('td').toggleClass("ui-state-hover", event.type == 'mouseover');
         });
         $this.find("caption").addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all");
         $this.find("th").addClass("ui-widget-header  ui-corner-all");
         $this.find("td").addClass("ui-widget-content");
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>


<br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th> Clumns1</th>
            <th> Column2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Some text
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href=""> Test link </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Some text
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href=""> Test link </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Some text
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href=""> Test link </a>
            </td>
        </tr>


    </table>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css to

```
a,
    a:link,
    a:active,  .ui-state-hover a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: blue ;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    a:visited, .ui-state-hover a:visited {
        color: purple ;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    a:hover,  .ui-state-hover a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Since your css comes after the include, it will overwrite the previous css